# Adding HTML file in xcode as UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, xcode

When I add an HTML file in UIWebView I am not getting the ful size image. only a quarter of the image is getting displayed. my code is

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
       [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ganesh" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
       webview.delegate=self;
```

}
The image is displayed as upside down. Can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your sample html.

Comment: Try this in your html file
`<head>
  <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</head>`

Comment: tried this still.... no change... :(

Comment: can you share your sample html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the frame of `webview` according to the `orientation`.

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/255 green:22.0/255 blue:11.0/255 alpha:1.0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faq-1" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO ];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: This is way you can show .HTML file on webView, here faq-1 is html file.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. But now i am getting half of the image only. That too broken from the middle.

Comment: In the Xib file of web view there is property Scaling : scales pages to fit, check this check box and, check opaque,clear graphics context,clip subviews,autoresize subviews,user Interaction Enabled and multiple touch then try.

Comment: tried all these then the image displays at the top left corner. broken from the middle, up side down.